# Quick Launch Menu Selector

Tags: 2013, javascript, css, quick-launch

The objective is to increase the size of the menu within the fly-out.  I applied the script below.  The only thing highlight that highlights the menu item when you hoover over does not appear any longer.  Can someone tell me what I am missing?

```
<style>
    #DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar 
    .menu-item
 {
     background-color:white;
     width:175px;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: provide some screenshots that will help to understand your problem better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the flyout menus can be selected using `#sideNavBox ul.dynamic` CSS selector

Comment: Thank you!  This worked, but the Flyout Container went back to it's original size.  When I remove the script you suggested it goes to the width change.  Do you know why this is?

Comment: You can keep your original style rule as well and add my suggested selector to your style sheet as well - Because they are selecting different elements. <style>/* rules for all menu items*/
    #DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar 
    .menu-item
 {
     background-color:white;
     width:175px;
 }  #sideNavBox ul.dynamic { /* rules for flyout menu*/ }
</style>